# Messagebox pops up after closing userform

Tags: vba, events, messagebox

I have a ComboBox in which the user is allowed to enter text. If the text is invalid, a message box pops up. I have used the "Exit" event type here.

Everything works fine, until the user enters invalid text and closes the userform with the "x" button or the "cancel" button. After closing the userform, the same message box pops up again.

Any ideas how could I deal with this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer. Instead of using the "Exit" type of event, I used "Before Update". It now works well!